# Should i use actionCreators in Component's folder level in my React-Redux project?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, directory-structure

I am using redux in my React project. And i have splitted my folders like in that picture:
[Folder structure of my store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrfY5.png)

But my folderActionCreators file so growed while i developing the project. [This is the end of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMBAe.png), i know its terrible. Is that so i decided to split my functions in folderActionCreator to folders and files. But i couldn't decide how should i do that?

I have come up one idea for that problem and i am not sure is that correct way.

I want to seperate every function inside of the folderActionCreators to component level for every needed component. Example of that:

I have component that named **FolderItem** and this component is inside of the FolderItem folder. [This is the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0pRx.png)

I want to create another folder inside of the FolderItem that name is **actionCreators** and move the action creator functions in here that **FolderItem's** need. In this case **FolderItem** component are using six action creator, [You can look the functions in here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9lab.png) and i want to move all of them inside of the **FolderItem** folder and import them from there.

So my question is, is that a bad practice? and if it is how should i organize my actionCreators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official recommendation (which might or might not work for you) is to place reducer, selectors and action creators that belong together into one "feature slice" file, next to components files for that feature into a "feature folder": [Redux Style Guide: Structure Files as Feature Folders with Single-File Logic](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#structure-files-as-feature-folders-with-single-file-logic)

Obviously sometimes you will have actions that might not really only belong to ONE reducer or feature - you can place those with the feature that belongs to them "the most", or just keep them separated as you want.

For an example of that file structure, you can also look at the file structures provided by the official Redux "Create React App" templates by calling
`npx create-react-app my-app --template redux` or `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript`

Also, this approach goes well with the [`createSlice` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) provided by the official redux toolkit that (among other things, like removing the need to write immutable updates by hand) automatically creates action creators for you for "case reducers" you declare.

Generally I can highly recommend you to look into [modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) and maybe go through the official [Redux "essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) that shows how to use modern Redux in practice.